# Getting {"error": "permission denied", "code": "S22"} on Workday REST API - Invoices endpoint

Tags: rest, workday-api

I am a little new to Workday REST API, and I am trying to use most of the endpoints to retrieve data for a project we are developing... I have been able to call the GET workers and GET supervisoryOrganizations, even if that required adding the correct scope and it worked great!

I have created an API Client for integrations which uses an ISU that I also created just for that, and granted permissions to it. Now the issue is that I am trying to access the invoices endpoint, the URL we are using as endpoint is {baseURL}/api/customerAccounts/v1/{myCompany}/invoices but every time I run the call I get the {"error": "permission denied", "code": "S22"} response , I have added the Scope: Customer Accounts, Project Billing to both, the ISU (on the security group) and the API Client itself but still getting this error... any ideas?

I tried to add the permissions to both, the security group that holds the ISU I created and the API Client, getting a new access token afterwards and still getting the same error , doing that process before has worked to get access to other endpoints like GET SupervisoryOrganizations but not in this case , maybe I am using an incorrect endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by generating a new refresh token... this time with a regular user who had access to view invoices and that fixed the issue , this user has access to everything in workday so if you encounter this issue, you can solve it like that but keep in mind this could be a security issue because that user has access to everything